# Umbraco - Redirect from Login to last currentpage

Tags: redirect, authentication, umbraco

I'm working in Umbraco and is currently using this code:

```
@if(Members.GetCurrentLoginStatus().IsLoggedIn) { 
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
}
```

In my login-template, so when I click on a protected page, I will be redirected to Login (that works) and then after successfull login be redirected back to the protected page. That works like a charm, but if I'm on Homepage and clicks "log in" and logs in, I get this problem when it is redirecting:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.
>   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
>   `@if(Members.GetCurrentLoginStatus().IsLoggedIn) {Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);}`**"**

I'm not using Visual Studio, only the CMS itself online so I can't access any controllers and do it myself.

Any Ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if there is no referrer it shouldn't redirect, right? So something like this should do?

```
@if(Members.GetCurrentLoginStatus().IsLoggedIn && Request.UrlReferrer != null) { 
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
}
```

Comment: @EmmyAndersson Excellent! Remember to accept my answer then ;-)